# Web3 + React: After successful transacion, try to get changed state but returns old value?

Tags: web3js, truffle, ethers.js, react

I'm trying to do something pretty simple using React, but I can't understand what's going on.

```
const A = await myContract.getA() // A = 0
  
myContract
       .setA(1) // should set A = 1 => confirmed by blockExplorer!
       .then(tx => tx.wait())
       .then(async () => {
             const a = await myContract.getA() // A = 0!   
        })
       .catch()
```

**If I refresh the page right after the `tx.wait()`, then the first statement returns A = 1** / meaning that the tx was successful and the state is changed, so why the state fetched after the tx is the old one??

Also added a setTimeout like with 10 seconds to be sure that's not the issue...

Ideas??? thanks

**EDIT:**
Created a `setInterval` to constantly call the contract every second. Eventually, the state gets updated, but it takes forever. Any ideas why takes so long to the state to change when using metamask?

If I call a server that uses `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` to get the state, changes are reflected almost instantly!

Answer (score 1):

When chaining promises each then has to return a promise for the subsequent then to proceed sequentially.

However in your code both the then methods are listening to the same promise returned by setA. As a result they wont be executed sequentially. Kindly check this explanation on how chaining promises work to get a clear picture. https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

As @bluebunny suggested chaining then `tx.wait` is the right way to address the issue

Answer (score 0):

You might have more success chaining the second `.then` call to `tx.wait()` -- that way, the second `then()` is for sure firing off /after/ the transaction has confirmed, rather than potentially before.

Ie., `(txn => txn.wait(1).then(do stuff))`

Comment: Yeah... actually that was exactly how I did it...
Tried async/await... you name it.

But I think that the problem is with react and references or smth like that. I created a separed Button, and call the function on click. THAT response contains the changed state